# SQL Search embeded in PHP for $var depending on search criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to gather information from several columns in an **SQL DB** and feed this into **PHP** form.

The **PHP** and embedded **SQL** query i am running at present is as follows:

```
< ?php

$region = $_POST['region']; 

        $serach = "Select clm_england, clm_ireland, clm_scotland, clm_wales
                    FROM tbl_data
                        WHEN    clm_england LIKE '%$region'
                                OR clm_ireland LIKE '%$region'
                                OR clm_scotland LIKE '%$region'
                                OR clm_wales LIKE '%$region'";

            $result = mysql_query($search);
            if(!$result)    {
            echo "Failed:" . mysql_error();
            }

? >
```

I need the query to see clm_england has england in this column and return the result if this is what is searched for. the search form has an option to search for each region or non at all. I am struggling to find a way to return the results based on the region selected to search for or return all results if no region is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `WHEN` and not `WHERE` in your request :

```
Select clm_england, clm_ireland, clm_scotland, clm_wales 
FROM tbl_data    
WHERE    clm_england LIKE '%$region'
OR clm_ireland LIKE '%$region'
OR clm_scotland LIKE '%$region'
OR clm_wales LIKE '%$region'
```